# Undefined socket in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to re-implement a compositor example of T yarn knitting. I cannot find plane MK2 and UV connector as had been explained in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AG4-sGcGyWI&list=LLuORS2hOBqsUJEgE645iWDQ&index=3&t=0s

I downloaded older blender versions, but I didnot find those nodes while search (shift+A).

Lastly, I downloaded the Github example file : https://github.com/enzyme69/blendersushi/issues/309

and I got this following error as shown in the attached image, what I should do to solve this problem.[image: undefined socket]

Comment: Are those nodes created by an add-on that is not installed in your version of blender?

Comment: I dont know, it is not mentioned. I have checked all add-on in blender

Comment: The solution is installing a sverchok add-on